# Adding a link under my image where I am using LightBox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering on how do I put a link under my Image so I can select it in my gallery.
 I have my li and my a href to show the image but I just need a link right under that. Thanks

Comment: Is this the original Lightbox/Lightbox2 that uses Prototype and Scriptaculous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try having both `<Img>` and `<a>` tag in `<li>` or a `<div>` as your case may be

Answer (score 0):

From the LightBox site:

**Can I insert links in the caption?**
Yes, but you need to convert quotes and greater and less than symbols into their html entity equivalents. For example:

```
<a href="images/image-4.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="&lt;a href=&quot;link.html&quot;&gt;my link&lt;/a&gt;">Image</a>
```